# Binding to static poperty in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I struggle to get a binding in code behind to a static property.
In WPF I´ve done it as shown below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LogListener.Instance}, Path=LogItem.LogType}" Margin="2" />
```

Now I want to bind "LogItem" against a new dp

```
#region LogItem

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LogItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LogItem", typeof(LogItem), typeof(NpLoggerControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(LogItem), LogItemPropertyChanged));

    private static void LogItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var type = source as NpLoggerControl;
        type?.LogItemPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void LogItemPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (LogItem) e.NewValue;
    }

    public LogItem LogItem
    {
        get { return (LogItem) GetValue(LogItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LogItemProperty, value); }
    }
```

I´ve no idea how to set it up in Code

Comment: There is no point of setting up the binding programmatically in this case. You could just set the dependency property to the value of the static LogType property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the properties just like you did in XAML:

```
textBlock.SetBinding(
    TextBlock.TextProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Source = LogListener.Instance,
        Path = new PropertyPath("LogItem.LogType")
    });
```